# Will replacement of CloudFlare by CloudFront make my AWS site faster?

Tags: cloudflare, amazon-cloudfront

Time to retrieval of the first byte of my image as a document from an Apache server at AWS (us-east-1) through CloudFlare in an attempt was about 1000 ms. This is unacceptably slow.

`curl -o/dev/null http://localhost` at my server takes about 10-30 ms. So, my Apache server seems not to be a bottleneck.

Do I assume correctly that it is CloudFlare bottleneck? (How then? Isn't it assumed to make my site faster, not slower?) What may be other reasons of slowness?

Is it expected to become much faster if I use AWS CloudFront instead (because it would be probably on the same network as my Apache)?

Comment: Another likely explanation is that `%h` in `LogFormat` of Apache causes slowdown sometimes, when accessing not localhost but a real server.

Comment: After I fixed the problem with `%h`, I still have 1,210 ms to the first byte of an image. This is weird.

Comment: Also, is CloudFlare (free version) as configurable as CloudFront in specifying which headers it should ignore for the purpose of caching?

Comment: You should check your headers to see if CloudFlare is actually caching the image, and if the expiration date is configured. In a properly configured scenario, images from your server should only be fetched once, and then, they should be served from CloudFlare's cache. On the other hand, there are other steps involved before 1st byte retrieval (DNS resolving, TLS/SSL handshake, etc.) You need to check on them to understand where is the issue.

Comment: While it would be significant to know if 1+seconds TTFB is from the Cloudflare cache or the origin server, this is really, REALLY BAD regardless. If you cannot replicate from the local machine (using a representative request) then the problem is outside the local machine - and you have no access to most of that. Report this to AWS support with appropriate supporting evidence.